# How to size elements according to rotated text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate my table headings so they're laid out vertically, but the surrounding th elements end up smaller than the div.  It's as though the th is sizing itself according to the div *before* the rotation.

How to I make the th automatically size based on the rotated div?

```css
.columnHeader {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**: This question got closed due to a dup, but that dup doesn't contain a great answer, so let me post a really clean solution here:

```css
.columnHeader {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One long heading</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two long headings</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the "vertical-rl" mode actually becomes left-to-right after the 180-degree rotation.

**Edit 2**: Thanks to those who provided answers, but I haven't upvoted or accepted most of them because, as I write this, they don't solve the original problem of how to size an element according to rotated text.  Some of them manually tweak the element size in pixels or ems, but of course I could have done that in the first place; any element's size can be tweaked manually.  That's not what I meant to ask for; if that's unclear, I could reword this post's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

> The `writing-mode` CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

```css
.columnHeader {
  writing-mode:vertical-lr;
  writing-mode:sideways-lr; /* FF or use transform and vertical-lr*/
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 1.2em;/* which means min-width according to the table-layout algorythm.*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One of any length</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codepen example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKQKBe

## edit

deleted and not, left here for infos.
<del>* You can use `float` and a pseudo element and a vertical [%`padding`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties) to draw a square to start width.</del>

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for '`padding-top`' and '`padding-bottom`'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1. 
>   Unlike `margin` properties, values for `padding` values cannot be negative. Like `margin` properties, **percentage values** for padding properties **refer to the width of the generated box's containing block**.

- <del>Adding a negative `margin-right` value will virtually reduce width of `.columHeader` to null.</del>
- <del>rotate `.columnHeader`</del>
- <del>add a `width` to `th` (which will be alike `min-width` ).</del>

```css
.columnHeader {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 1.2em;
}

.columnHeader {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -20em;
}

.columnHeader:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One of any length</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<del>codepen example</del>

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Cqkig

Comment: Thanks, G-Cyr.  "writing-mode:vertical-lr" seems to be the key!  I've edited the question to include a couple more settings that, I think, would give people what they usually want: a 180-degree rotation so text goes bottom-up and "white-space: nowrap" so that it stays nice and narrow (which is probably why someone would use vertical table headings in the first place).  If that answer were on its own, I'd accept it as the right answer.

Comment: @Doradus i edited the answer , not that if you followed the linked example, there also syntax for older browsers, a comment about sideways  and i used transform:scale(-1) instead rotate ;) .

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate th

```
th {
  background-color: #f88;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```css
table td {
  text-align:center;
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Hiren, though that doesn't really address the question in the title of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding to the div

```css
.columnHeader {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  padding: 10px 0;
}

th {
  background-color: #f88;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">One</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="columnHeader">Two</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, DerJP.  I was aware I could manually tweak the element sizes; I meant to ask for something that would work naturally, on its own.

Comment: I understand :)