# Table with fixed cell and upward-orientation header

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to make this

[image]

Is it possible to only use HTML and CSS to achieve both problem(upward-orientation and square cell)?

the upward-orientation cell width should match the line-height

if I have to use javascript, can it be done without using any framework?

Thank You

EDIT 1:

This is what I currently done

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

        table td {
            border: 1px solid #555;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }

    .vertical {
        transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2">Horizontal Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Horizontal Sub-Header</td>
        <td>Horizontal Sub-Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="vertical">Vertical Header</td>
        <td class="vertical">Vertical Sub-Header</td>
        <td>[0][0]</td>
        <td>[0][1]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="vertical">Vertical Sub-Header</td>
        <td>[1][0]</td>
        <td>[1][1]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

which turn into this :

[image]

and then I change the structure of table header and make the .vertical class like this :

```
<style>
    . . .
    .vertical {
        display: inline-block;
        . . .
    }
</style>
<table>
    . . .
        <td rowspan="2"><span class="vertical">Vertical Header</span></td>
        <td><span class="vertical">Vertical Sub-Header</span></td>
    . . .
</table>
```

and managed to achieve like this :

[image]

the `width` of the vertical header's cell does not wrap to vertical line height.

Comment: What code do you have so far?  It is possible, but without knowing what you have so far, we can't guide you to the solution.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: you have a duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622246/how-to-size-elements-according-to-rotated-text/46622455 (about table linking to that example i believe https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/EKQKBe )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kukkuz answer is probably better, but if you want to do it with an actual table, I guess you can use `writing-mode` and `transform` CSS options.
So it can be done like this:

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.vertical-header span,
.vertical-header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.vertical-header span {
  transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="2">h-header</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>sub-h-header1</th>
        <th>sub-h-header2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" class="vertical-header"><span>v-header</span></th>
        <th class="vertical-header"><span>sub-v-header1</span></th>
        <td>0,0</td>
        <td>0,1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="vertical-header"><span>sub-v-header2</span></th>
        <td>1,0</td>
        <td>1,1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Reference:

- [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)
- [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
- [text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

Comment: thank you for this answer, I don't know if it's cross-browser compatible or not, but this should do

Answer (score 2):

So here is one way to do it using CSS Grid layout:

- set your layout using `grid-template-areas`
- `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` will set your layout dimensions
- set vertical text using:

  ```
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  ```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. . heading heading' 
                       '. . sub-heading1 sub-heading2' 
                       'heading-v sub-heading1-v s1 s2' 
                       'heading-v sub-heading2-v s3 s4';
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 150px 150px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 150px 150px;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background: cadetblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: #fff;
}

.vertical {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading {
  grid-area: heading;
}

.sub-heading1 {
  grid-area: sub-heading1;
}

.sub-heading2 {
  grid-area: sub-heading2;
}

.heading-v {
  grid-area: heading-v;
}

.sub-heading1-v {
  grid-area: sub-heading1-v;
}

.sub-heading2-v {
  grid-area: sub-heading2-v;
}

.s1 {
  grid-area: s1;
}

.s2 {
  grid-area: s2;
}

.s3 {
  grid-area: s3;
}

.s4 {
  grid-area: s4;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="heading">Horizontal header</div>
  <div class="sub-heading1">Horizontal sub-header</div>
  <div class="sub-heading2">Horizontal sub-header</div>
  <div class="heading-v vertical">Vertical header</div>
  <div class="sub-heading1-v vertical">Vertical sub-header</div>
  <div class="sub-heading2-v vertical">Vertical sub-header</div>
  <div class="s1"></div>
  <div class="s2"></div>
  <div class="s3"></div>
  <div class="s4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, but currently I need to use `table`